# VBA - How to output a variable to a particular row and column in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

This code should find the correct cell (in the column corresponding to it's 'length' and the next empty row) in which to output a variable.

I'm getting the error message:

> method range of object _worksheet failed

on lines 13 onward containing "outputcolumn"

In the MsgBox lines, the correct column and row number are being displayed, so I am not sure why it is not happy with my outputcolumn in particular.

```
Private Sub OutputRowAndColumn()

    'Choose correct column: Find the length column and name this outputcolumn
    Dim cell As Range, outputcolumn As Integer
    Set cell = Range("FindLength").Find(Range("Length").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        outputcolumn = cell.Column
    End If

    MsgBox "Output column is number " & outputcolumn & "."

    'Choose correct row: If the cell to the left of "cell" is empty then this is the first row of output otherwise find next empty cell down
    If Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & "4").Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        outputrow = 4 ''' error msg '''
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & "5").Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        outputrow = 5
    Else
        outputrow = Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & "4").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
    End If

    MsgBox "Output row is number " & outputrow & "."

    'Copy values 1, 2 and 3 from sheet 2 to sheet 1
    Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & outputrow).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("Value1").Value ''' error msg '''
    Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & outputrow).Offset(0, 2).Value = Sheet2.Range("Value2").Value
    Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & outputrow).Offset(0, 3).Value = Sheet2.Range("Value3").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputcolumn` is a numeric value (you defined it as `Integer`, but you always should define variables holding row or column numbers as `long` to avoid overflow errors).

So let's say `outputcolumn` gets the number `2` (column `B`). You write `Sheet1.Range(outputcolumn & "4")`. To access a range by it's address, You would have to write something like `Range("B4")`, but what you write is `Range(2 & "4")`, which means `Range("24")`, and that is an invalid address for a `Range`.

You could try to translate the column number `2` to a `B`, but there is an easier way to access a cell when you know the row and column number: Simply use the `cells`-property:

```
If Sheet1.Cells(4, outputcolumn).Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
' (or)
If Sheet1.Cells(4, outputcolumn+1).Value = "" Then
```

Just note that the order of the parameters is row, column.

Comment: be careful with isempty versus empty string literals +

Answer (score 0):

"outputcolumn" is numeric in your case and when using .Range(), it needs to be a proper alphanumeric cell reference like "C5", not all numeric.

I haven't tried it directly but changing this ...

```
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    outputcolumn = cell.Column
End If
```

... to this ...

```
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    outputcolumn = Split(cell.Address, "$")(1)
End If
```

... will go a long way to helping you.